# I have 3 folders in IE favourites that I am unable to remove/delete. Help please

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, internet-explorer-11

I have 3 folders in IE favourites that I am unable to remove or delete.I keep getting a message for each folder "This is no longer located in C:\Users\Bob\Favourites. Verify the item's location and try again." But when I open C:\Users\Bob\Favourites they are all there. I cannot delete them from this folder either without getting the same message. I think this has to be a registry issue but I don't know what to do to eradicate these 3 'ghost' folders.

Comment: What makes you think it's a registry issue? It's more likely a file-system issue (Favorites are just shortcuts (.LNK), which are files). Have you done a disk check yet to ensure you don't have file system corruption?

Comment: There a reason Favorite isn't spelled right?

Comment: Sorry about spelling Ramhound - I'm in UK and used to British English, but it isn't my spelling causing the problem!

Comment: It is spelt right, the US spells it wrong. ;)

Comment: Techie007 - should I just run Glarysoft Utilities then, do you think it might pick this up? Bob

Comment: No, you should use [Windows' in-built disk checker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/check-your-hard-disk-for-errors) to start (ps: make a full backup before allowing utilities to do any repairs to the disk).

Answer (score 0):

I very well could be registry, First I would run a disk cleanup and a chkdsk and make sure to rebuild your icon cache. Info about that is [HERE](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-disk-cleanup-in-windows-7-and-vista.html) and [Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/using-windows-7-how-do-i-run-chkdsk/a68b3e4d-1a42-e011-9767-d8d385dcbb12).

Second, You can try to add a take ownership to the file or folder, and try to delete it, Info about that is [Here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1911-take-ownership-shortcut.html). (P.S. This is great to have for several situations.)

Third, if it is registry, Try to run CCleaner which is found [Here](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner), and It has a registry tool.

If those don't work, we can get some more information and go from there, Also, are you making sure you are running as Administrator, and that in the control panel, the display protected system files is unchecked, if that is ticked, you will see all kinds of system files that you don't want to see.

Comment: Also I just verified that I can delete the same files on my system with no problem, they are not even ghost hidden files.

Comment: Hi trenten, thank you for giving me some ideas. I did the disk cleanup and chkdsk and also the take-ownership trick, but alas, to no avail. CCleaner didn't 'see' the files and I also tried shredding them with Glarysoft, but that didn't work either. However I have managed to get rid of one of them by downloading Unlocker from Filehippo and zapping them each with it. Finally I had to boot into Linux (Zorin) to delete the remaining two there. When I rebooted into W7 all the blasted things had finally disappeared. Once again, many thanks for your trouble. Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, at least you were able to get them deleted.